Как заполнить поля разными данными
Приветы. Разное кол-во инпутов(полей)на форме,
необходимо собрать все инпуты, пройтись в каждом(видимо циклом) и заполнить разными данными.
Заполнять будем, ну пусть так:
в первом поле вставим 10, в остальных добавляем к вставленному числу 10 и так до последнего поля.
Пример заполнения, при 5 полей в форме:
'
10 20 30 40 50
'''
    input_text_fields = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "LOCATOR") #собираем все поля
    for i in input_text_fields:
        i.send_keys("10")

'''

Можно немного модифицировать ваш код:
input_text_fields = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "LOCATOR") # Собираем все поля

value = 10
for i in input_text_fields:
    i.send_keys(str(value))
    value += 10

Должно работать, точно по описанию
